# Can I use 'LIKE' or % in IN parameters while using Pivot in oracle?

Tags: oracle, pivot, sql-like

The current output:

```
PORT    BANDWIDTH   TYPE

XE-5/1/0    29267   XE

XE-5/1/0    48154   XE

GE-4/0/0    443 GE

XE-3/0/0    28077   XE

GE-1/0/0    1032    GE

GE-1/0/6    2285    GE

XE-5/1/0        XE
```

The query:

```
select *
from (select d.port,d.bandwidth from dummy123 d where d.bandwidth is not null) 
pivot (sum(bandwidth) as totalbandwidth for port in ( 'GE%' ,'XE%'))
```

Is there any way to use like or % operator while using pivot?

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't. But you can use substr to truncate the string. E.g. try the following:

```
select *
from (select substr(d.port,1,2) portmask,
             d.bandwidth
      from dummy123 d where d.bandwidth is not null) 
pivot (sum(bandwidth) as totalbandwidth for portmask in ( 'GE' ,'XE'))
```